# Swift 3, sort class by property and populate table view

Tags: uitableview, sorting, swift3

I'm a complete beginner, and searched the internet for a solution.
I would like to sort the places by the distance to the user, and show the names (sorted by the nearest to farest distance) in a table view.
I was able to sort another array and show in table view, and I was able to sort other places by distances, thanks to stackoverflow search.
But I'm not able to put it together, and show the name of these places in the table view.

I hope I described everything good enough for you to understand my problem.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class Places {

let name: String
let facility: String
let operated: String
let location: CLLocation

init(name: String, facility: String, operated: String, location: CLLocation){

    self.name = name
    self.facility = facility
    self.operated = operated
    self.location = location

}

}

let place1 = Places(name: "Name1", facility: "Hospital", operated: "privat", location: CLLocation(latitude: 12.953761, longitude: 100.906278))
let place2 = Places(name: "Name2", facility: "Hospital", operated: "privat", location: CLLocation(latitude: 12.944278, longitude: 100.887897))
let place3 = Places(name: "Name3", facility: "Hospital", operated: "privat", location: CLLocation(latitude: 12.935769, longitude: 100.886871))
let place4 = Places(name: "Name4", facility: "Hospital", operated: "sozial", location: CLLocation(latitude: 12.927889, longitude:  100.884304))
let place5 = Places(name: "Name5", facility: "Hospital", operated: "sozial", location: CLLocation(latitude: 12.966825, longitude: 100.906108))

var places: [Places] = [place1, place2, place3, place4, place5]
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CLLocationManagerDelegate{

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return(places.count)
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

//Here comes the error        
cell.textLabel?.text = places.name[indexPath.row] 
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
    return(cell)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first `subscript` with your `Array` then need to access its properties `name`, `facility`, `operated` and `location`.

**It should be**

```
cell.textLabel?.text = places[indexPath.row].name
```

**Instead of**

```
cell.textLabel?.text = places.name[indexPath.row]
```

**Note :** Don't set `tableFooterView` in `cellForRowAt` method instead of that set it inside the `viewDidLoad`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!!! Regarding the tableFooterView, I receive the following error message if I set it inside the viewDidLoad "Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)"